# How to display a list of all gradients in Tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm using Tensorboard 1.5 and I would like to see how my gradients are doing.

Here is an example of layer I am using:

```
net = tf.layers.dense(features, 40, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, 
                        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

And here is my optimizer:

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

For my model parameters I create summaries this way:

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
```

Is there a similar way to get the all gradients in a for loop to create my summaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first get the gradients using `compute_gradients` of the optimizer and then pass them to summary:

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)

# Calculate the gradients for the batch of data
grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)

# Add histograms for gradients.
for grad, var in grads:
  if grad is not None:
    summaries.append(tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name + '/gradients', grad))
```

And then to perform the training, you can call the `apply_gradients` of optimizer:

```
# Apply the gradients to adjust the shared variables.
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
```

for more, you can go to [tensorflow cifar10 tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py).